# haml rspec missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, haml

This really caught me unguarded. The stocks/index.html.haml renders without problem in browser after I installed the haml-rails gem. However, when I tried to test it using rspec/capybara

```
describe "StockPages" do
  describe "stocks/index.html.haml" do
    before {visit stocks_path}
    subject {page}
    it { should have_selector('table#Result')  }
  end
end
```

I got this error:

```
Failure/Error: before {visit stocks_path}
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template stocks/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

How do I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: How have you added the `haml-rails` gem to your `Gemfile`, is it only in the development group?

Comment: How stupid I am! You are right. So I should include it in test group also? How about production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to render Haml templates, you need the `haml` gem loaded. `haml-rails` does call `require 'haml'`, but if you’ve only added `haml-rails` to the development group in your `Gemfile` then `haml` will also only get loaded in development.

In order to fix this, you need to either move `haml-rails` out of any group so that it always gets loaded (and so `haml` also always gets loaded), or add `gem 'haml'` to your `Gemfile` (outside of any group). The first option (move `haml-rails` out of the development group) is likely the easiest, but you might want to leave it in the development group and explicitly add `gem 'haml'` in order to avoid loading unneeded code in production.